# How to solve error when importing XML in google sheets? (could not fetch the URL)

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I would like to scrape price in the specific product link, but it turns error when I wrote the formula like this.

=IMPORTXML([https://www.tokopedia.com/foodrepublic/koepoe-koepoe-natrium-benzoat-33-gr-pengawet-makanan-minuman-halal,"//*[@id='pdp_comp-product_content']/div/div[2]/div"](https://www.tokopedia.com/foodrepublic/koepoe-koepoe-natrium-benzoat-33-gr-pengawet-makanan-minuman-halal,%22//*%5B@id=%27pdp_comp-product_content%27%5D/div/div%5B2%5D/div%22))

[page i want to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8rEe.png)

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61052087/19846219) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to enclose the URL with double quotes. the correct syntax is:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tokopedia.com/foodrepublic/koepoe-koepoe-natrium-benzoat-33-gr-pengawet-makanan-minuman-halal"; 
 "//*[@id='pdp_comp-product_content']/div/div[2]/div")
```